# How reliable is pstack as a profiling tool?

Tags: linux, debugging, linux-kernel, profiling

I've been using pstack (called in a loop periodically) as a substitute for a real profiling tool. I've noticed that even though there's more then 85% cpu usage for that pid in top, pstack shows the pid being blocked on I/O more often than being CPU bound.

How's pstack implemented? Is there any reason why pstack would be more susceptible to attaching to the pid when it's actually blocked on I/O?

Answer (score 0):

You say you're calling `pstack` periodically in a loop - i.e. in a separate process (B) from the one you are profiling(A). If they are running in a single core, then B is more likely to "wake up" when A is blocked.

Regardless, I would trigger `pstack` manually, on the theory that not many samples are needed. Rather the samples I *do* get need to be scrutinized, not just lumped together.

In general, it's good to take samples during I/O time as well as CPU time, because both I/O and CPU wastage can make your program slow.
If it somewhat inflates one or the other, that's fairly harmless, assuming your real goal is to precisely identify things to optimize, rather than just get precise measurements of fuzzy things like functions.

Comment: Yes pstack is invoked in a loop from bash. It's a 16-core machine, so I'm not sure realistically what's the likelihood of the pid being profiled and pstack running on the same core. On a single-core machine, that would make a lot of sense.

Comment: Also I agree you need to profile both I/O calls and CPU intensive calls. This is just a hunch - I've noticed pstack always reporting an I/O call at the top of the stack lot more than what you'd expect considering the process has nearly 85-90% cpu usage continuously in top. You'd expect it to be CPU bound.

Comment: @Harish: Whenever I do this, it's because I want to speed up the code, so I would say in your case - the stack sample is in I/O, but the stack tells you the purpose of the I/O. Maybe you can find a way to do less of it. OTOH, you can just discard the samples in I/O and look at the CPU ones. What's it doing and why? If on even as few as *two* samples you see it doing something that you could do less or not at all, it will pay off, guaranteed. Then do it all over again. In this way, you keep nibbling away at it, until you can surprise yourself - it's a *lot* faster.